# jsFiddle issue with specific word

Tags: jsfiddle

I am unable to get jsfiddle to save any fiddles containing the word allocation

example

```
    var care_allocation = 34; alert(care_allocation)
```

Pressing **save** just clears the screen.

I'm assuming jsfiddle maybe uses some reserved keywords, is there a list of these and can anybody suggest a workaround. I realize I could just use a different variable name but I have already written an awful lot of code.

Thanks very much in advance

[EDIT]
Running the fiddle without saving is fine, this issue occurs when I try and SAVE it. I have asked a colleague who is able to re create the issue

Comment: also allocation in comments appears not to work either.

Answer (score 0):

No. **Allocation** is not a reserved word in jsFiddle. I have tried out and working properly. Please check settings on the left side.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can I check you managed to SAVE the fiddle, RUNNING with out saving works fine however I cannot save it, I have asked a few colleagues to try also and they have the same issue.

Comment: cheers Railhan, i'm now investigating the issue across different browsers. As when i press save on your fiddle in chrome it also resets it!